# ParserError: Expected '{' but got '}' I keep getting this error when I try to compile my code

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-design, compiler

I get this error every time that I try to compile my code. These curly brackets run from the beginning of my contract to the very end. I'm new to smart contracts, and this does not make much sense to me as every function and body of the contract must be contained in curly brackets.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    bool favoriteBool;

    struct People{
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    
    People[1] public people;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
   
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
    return favoriteNumber;
    }
    
    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, name_))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix. I was missing curly brackets on my "function addPerson".